# When does css file retrieve background-img URL?

Tags: html, css

When a .css file uses a url for an image file, does the client retrieve that image when the .css file is loaded or does it wait until the specific class is assigned to an element?

For example -

A user loads home.html with style.css referenced in the header.  The home page does not include any elements with class `attach_background_image`, but within style.css we have

```
.attach_background_image{
    background-image:URL(background.png);
}
```

Will background.png be retrieved when home.html is hit?  Or does the image only get requested when an element meets the css selector criteria?

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools, network panel, and find out ...

Comment: @CBroe it isn't bad to ask a question if you think it could be answered faster by the community than running the test yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will be retrieved on page load, when the class .attach_background_image is loaded

Comment: I stopped being lazy and verified for Chrome, IE, FF and even Edge.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The whole CSS-file is loaded on page-load, <del>so that's when the file will be retrieved. That the CSS in the file isn't actually used anywhere doesn't matter.</del>

**EDIT**
Sorry, I realised the original answer was wrong - the CSS file is loaded (all of it), but the external resources are loaded on a on-use basis, so until that class or element is present on the page, it will not run the GET-request to fetch it.

That means that if you for instance have a javascript change classes, the image will get retrieved, which of course can lead to slightly longer load-times than expected (depending on where the resource is located, and the size of the image)

Comment: The CSS file is loaded but I'm pretty sure the background-image is not loaded until it is used, I believe it is loaded in this way: HTML -> CSS -> IMG

Comment: The entire .css file and all everything it references?  Is that behavior the same across browsers?

Comment: Do an inspect of the HTML-file when you load it, and look at the NET-tab, please...

Comment: @Isaac I'm sure he is wrong, look in your Chrome for example, you can easily see that image path does not impact the CSS File, and if the class is not in your page, the image won't even be loaded

Comment: Actually, I am wrong, and I apologize (it was a caching issue when I tested) - the actual image only gets loaded / retrieved when the element / class/ whatever is loaded. The CSS is completely loaded, of course, so if you add the classname via javascript, for instance, the image will be retrieved then (which will result in another HTTP-request)